# Keeping track of top 'N' queries in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrnet, solr4

Is there any way we can keep track of the top 'N' queries in solr? If not, can someone give me any pointers on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not functionality supplied directly within Solr. However a few ways are outlined in this previous post from the Solr Mailing List:

[Any way to get top 'n' queries searched from Solr?](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Any-way-to-get-top-n-queries-searched-from-Solr-td767165.html)

Comment: Thanks I have already visited the link that you've provided.. I was just curious to know if there were any other alternatives..